# How to use async/await correctly to display Xamarin Forms ActivityIndicator

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have code that gets executed when a `ListView` item is selected. Since this code can take a noticeable amount of time to execute I want to display an `ActivityIndicator` while it is running.

I have read through a lot of posts about the `ActivityIndicator` and I believe I have it setup correctly. I'm pretty sure my problem is due to the running code blocking the UI thread since the UI freezes completely during the process.

I've worked through every variation I have been able to find for using async/await with no luck so I'm assuming that I am still doing something incorrectly.

Here is my code:

```
private ListItem selectedList;
public ListItem SelectedList
{
    get
    {
        return selectedList;
    }
    set
    {
        if (selectedList != value)
        {
            var oldValue = selectedList;
            selectedList = value;
            buildThisList();
        }
    }
}

private async void buildThisList()
{
    StatusBarIsVisibile = true; 
    ThisList = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        return await buildBnBList(SelectedList, selectedLocation, 
                         thisYearList.ListId)
                         .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }).Result;  // 1.8 seconds
    StatusBarIsVisibile = false;
    ThisList.MainVM = this;
    ThisList.BuildView();
    PIShowListHeaderText = SelectedList.Title.Trim();
}

private async Task<BnBList> buildBnBList(ListItem pSelectedList, State pselectedLocation, int pListId)
{
    BnBList newList = new BnBList(pSelectedList, pselectedLocation, pListId);
    List<BirdsnBflysMaster> bbfList = 
         App.BnBRepo.GetBirdsnBflys(selectedList.ListType); // 1.3 seconds
    Lists parentList = App.BnBRepo.GetAList(SelectedList.ListId); // .5 seconds
    BnBItem newBnBItem;
    foreach (BirdsnBflysMaster bbf in bbfList) // .4 seconds
    {
        newBnBItem = new BnBItem(parentList, bbf, selectedLocation, newList, thisYearList.ListId);
        newList.ListAll.Add(newBnBItem);
        if (newBnBItem.ListTypeID == "Bird")
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }            
    return newList;
}
```

So:

- `buildThisList` gets called when the `SelectedList` property changes.
- `buildThisList` calls `buildBnBList` which is the time consuming process.
- `buildBnBList` has nothing in it that is done asynchronously.
- `StatusBarIsVisible` is bound to both `IsVisible` and `IsRunning` of the `ActivityIndicator`.

How can I code this so that executing `buildBnBList` does not block the UI thread?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you a mixing blocking (`.Result`) with async code which risks causing deadlocks. `async void` should be avoided, unless in an even handler.

So then why not do just that?

Create an event and event handler.

```
public event EventHandler ListSelected = delegate { }
```

this should now allow you to create an event handler

```
private async void OnListSelected(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    StatusBarIsVisibile = true; 
    ThisList = await buildBnBList(SelectedList, selectedLocation, thisYearList.ListId);

    StatusBarIsVisibile = false;
    ThisList.MainVM = this;
    ThisList.BuildView();
    PIShowListHeaderText = SelectedList.Title.Trim();
}
```

You would obviously subscribe to the event *(early in the life-cycle of course)*

```
this.ListSelected += OnListSelected;
```

and raise the event as needed

```
private ListItem selectedList;
public ListItem SelectedList {
    get {
        return selectedList;
    }
    set {
        if (selectedList != value) {
            var oldValue = selectedList;
            selectedList = value;
            OnListSelected(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I think I understand what you suggested. I implemented it in my code but it doesn't make a difference. If I set StatusBarIsVisibile = true before I run, the ActivityIndicator is spinning. When I click on a list item the spinner stops and nothing else happens in the UI until OnListSelected finishes. At that point the ActivityIndicator starts spinning again and the item i selected gets highlighted.